# select 2 fields and return a sorted array with their distinct values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say we have the following docs:

```
{a: 1, b: 2},
{a: 2, b: 0},
{a: 3, b: 1}
```

I want a query that will return:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I want to know if there is a way to do this faster than:

- just making 2 queries, one selecting `a`, the other selecting `b` then merging in my application.
- using map reduce(which was reaaaaly slow compared to the previous method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) our documents and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator to return an array of "a" and "b" within the collection.

In the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator you use  the [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator to filter out the duplicates.

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": null, 
            "a": { "$push": "$a" }, 
            "b": { "$push": "$b" } 
        }}, 
        { "$project": {
            "_id": 0, 
            "merged": { "$setUnion": [ "$a", "$b" ] } 
        }} 
    ]
)
```

which produces:

```
{ "merged" : [ 3, 2, 0, 1 ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that

```
db.getCollection('yourdocs').aggregate([
     { 
        $project: { 
            values: [ "$a", "$b" ] 
        } 
     },
     {
         $unwind: "$values"
     },
     {
         $group: {
             _id: "distinctValues",
             values: {
                 $addToSet: "$values"
             }
         }
     }
])
```

which will result in

```
{
    "_id" : "distinctValues",
    "values" : [ 
        0, 
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ]
}
```

Update: Just read you want it sorted which is not guaranteed with `$addToSet`. If sorting is crucial for you just add the following to the aggregation pipeline after the stages above

```
{
    "$unwind": "$values"
},
{
    "$sort": { 
        "values": 1
    }
},
{
    "$group": { 
        _id: "distinctValues",
        "values": {
            "$push": "$values"
        }
    }
}
```