# Sorting documents with mongodb collection in a non-consecutive way by object id value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am needing to sort results from a collection in a very particular way.

I have, as an example, the following records

```
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 3"}
{"item": "value 3"}
```

I need to show them in a non-consecutive way, for example.

```
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 1"}
{"item": "value 2"}
{"item": "value 3"}
{"item": "value 3"}
```

Showing the rest, if there is no option, consecutively, I would like to resolve directly with a mongo query, and not programmatically after obtaining the results because according to the database, the first 100 results can be all consecutive.

In my colleges I use Ids as a value that I should not repeat.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

Recently I find this post: [select 2 fields and return a sorted array with their distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883879/select-2-fields-and-return-a-sorted-array-with-their-distinct-values) that maybe with that aprouch I can solve my situation.

UPDATE:

Regarding @dnickless comment, a possible solution is $zip operator, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/

If I get groups of values in array maibe this can be a solution to order the results?

Comment: So how would you describe your sorting pattern in words? "Everything that has "value1" or "value2" shall be at the start and alternating and all the rest then just follows afterwards?

Comment: Yes, something like that... I have 6 differents values that I need to alternat, value1 and value2 and value3, etc.. are ObjectsIds I mention that in case that help to the answer

Comment: But value3 does not take part in this alternating scheme above? Is this your real data?

Comment: Also, which MongoDB version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.18, and no, this is not my real data, my documents are like this:
{"newspaper" : ObjectId("5a29def597c90d60c357b7b1")}
{"newspaper" : ObjectId("5a340b51d90732634d7b368b")}
{"newspaper" : ObjectId("5a340b79d90732634d7b368c")}

Comment: ...so I guess you've got three specific newspapers that you would want to spit out articles (or something) for in an alternating fashion? And then all the rest?

Comment: You are right.. I have all post of all newspaper on the same collection, and I can filter by newspaper id, and I want to see the latest post alternating the results by newspaper.

Comment: I can think of a potential solution using the zip operator in 3.4 but I'm unable to help with v3.2 - I'm sorry.

Comment: I can update the version of mongo to the latest without problem, that not will be an issue, if you have some ideas, I'm glade to read your aproach to do this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes the MongoDB v3.4 version - assumption is that `$unwind` preserves the document order (not really documented but seems to work in my unsharded local test environment). If that assumption is wrong we need some more magic:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "articletype": {
            $switch: { // we calculate a field which will hold either 1, 2, 3 for the three kinds of special newspapers or 4 for all the rest
                branches: [
                    { case: { $eq: [ "$newspaper", ObjectId("5a29def597c90d60c357b7b1") ] }, then: 1 },
                    { case: { $eq: [ "$newspaper", ObjectId("5a340b51d90732634d7b368b") ] }, then: 2 },
                    { case: { $eq: [ "$newspaper", ObjectId("5a340b79d90732634d7b368c") ] }, then: 3 }
                ],
                default: 4
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: { // we group everything together to get the articles in an array per newspaper type
        _id: "null", // everything goes in the same group
        "articlesfornp1": { // all articles for newspaper type 1
            $push: { // create and array that holds
                $cond: [ // 
                    { $eq: [ "$newspapertype", 1 ] }, // if the newspaper type is 1
                    "$$ROOT", // then document we're looking at just now
                    null // otherwise null
                ]
            }
        },
        "articlesfornp2": { $push: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$articletype", 2 ] }, "$$ROOT", null ] } }, // same logic as above for newspaper type 2
        "articlesfornp3": { $push: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$articletype", 3 ] }, "$$ROOT", null ] } }, // same logic as above for newspaper type 3
        "articlesfornp4": { $push: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$articletype", 4 ] }, "$$ROOT", null ] } } // same logic as above for remaining articles
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "articlesInOrder": { // we create a new array called "articlesInOrder"
            $concatArrays: [{ // which shall be the combination of
                $map: { // some transformed array
                    input: { // of
                        $zip: { // the $zipped contents of newspaper types 1-3
                            inputs: [
                                {
                                    $filter: { // with null values eliminated
                                        input: "$articlesfornp1",
                                        cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] }
                                    }
                                },
                                { $filter: { input: "$articlesfornp2", cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] } } }, // filter null values for newspaper type 2
                                { $filter: { input: "$articlesfornp3", cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] } } } // filter null values for newspaper type 3
                            ],
                            useLongestLength: true // make sure we do not miss any articles because of different numbers of articles for newspaper types 1-3
                        }
                    },
                    in: { // again filter null values using $map because we're filtering an array of arrays (output of $zip) here
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$this",
                            cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, { // and by the remaining articles
                $filter: {
                    input: "$articlesfornp4",
                    cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] }
                }
            }]
        },
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$articlesInOrder" // flatten array
}, {
    $unwind: "$articlesInOrder" // flatten array
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { // restore structure
        newRoot: "$articlesInOrder"
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi dnickles, this query fails with the next error: The full response is:
{ 

    "ok" : 0.0, 

    "errmsg" : "'newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: null. Type of resulting value: 'null'. Input document: {_id: \"null\", articlesInOrder: null}", 

    "code" : NumberInt(40228), 

    "codeName" : "Location40228"

}

Comment: It certainly worked against my handcrafted test data (based on your above comment)... Can you post some sample data set, please?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. My understanding was that out of all your newspapers there are three special ones for which you'd want to return the articles at the start of your list in an alternating fashion. That's why I've got the three ObjectIds hard coded (taken from your comment - if they do not match your data then that'd explain the error you're getting)... If you want to alternate all articles then that'd require a different solution, of course.

Comment: I have another suspicion where this error could come from which I'll check tomorrow. Got to sleep now - I think I'm getting sick...